# Como criar um método de soma em que o resultado apareça no campo edit text

Tags: java, android, edittext

Estou criando uma aplicação e gostaria que o resultado da operação preço de custo mais percentual de lucro aparecesse no resultado preço de venda sendo que este último não poderá ser editado no momento de salvar os dados. Peço que sejam o mais específicos possíveis pois não tenho muita experiência. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ProdutoDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;


 public class CadProdutos extends Activity {

private ImageView imgView = null;
static final int SALVAR = 0, EXCLUIR = 1, LIMPAR = 2;
EditText edId, edDescricao, edPrecoDeCusto, edPercDeLucro, edPrecoDeVenda;
ProdutoDao prodDao;
Produto produto;
ImageView imgFoto; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad_produtos);
    edId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdId);
    edDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdDescricao);
    edPrecoDeCusto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeCusto);
    edPrecoDeCusto.addTextChangedListener(new MonetaryMask(edPrecoDeCusto));
    edPercDeLucro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPercDeLucro);
    edPrecoDeVenda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeVenda);
    edPrecoDeVenda.addTextChangedListener(new MonetaryMask(edPrecoDeVenda));

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);

    Produto produtoRecebido = (Produto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Produto");
    if (produtoRecebido != null) {
        montaTela(produtoRecebido);
    } else {
        montaTela(new Produto());
    }

    Button btn1Salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btn1Salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            if (pro.getId() > 0) {
                getProDao().alterar(pro);
            } else {
                getProDao().inserirProduto(pro);
            }
            ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Salvo com Sucesso",
                    ToastManager.INFORMATION);

        }
    });

    Button btnLimpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLimpar);

    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            montaTela(new Produto());
        }
    });

    Button bt2Excluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2Excluir);
    bt2Excluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadProdutos.this);
            builder.setTitle("Deseja Excluir?");
            builder.setMessage("O produto será deletado!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getProDao().excluir(pro);
                    montaTela(new Produto());
                    ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Produto Excluído",
                            ToastManager.INFORMATION);

                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(CadProdutos.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });
}

private void montaTela(Produto produto) {
    edId.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getId()));
    edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());
    edPrecoDeCusto.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeCusto()));
    edPercDeLucro.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPercDeLucro()));
    edPrecoDeVenda.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));


}

public ProdutoDao getProDao() {
    if (prodDao == null) {
        prodDao = new ProdutoDao();
    }
    return prodDao;
}

public void tirarFoto(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");


            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Esse método seria chamado pelo *click* num botão ou de forma automática ao preencher os outros campos?

Comment: @ramaral A ideia era fazer automático ao preencher os campos..

Comment: Procure por TextWatcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você utiliza o `TextWatcher` para aplicar a máscara, sugiro utilizar o `View.OnFocusChangeListener`

**Problema:** Ele só irá funcionar quando o usuário tirar o foco de um dos campos!

Exemplo de implementação:

```
OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
        {
        // Aqui você pega os valores dos campos, realiza a soma e adiciona no no outro campo
        }
    }
};

edPrecoDeCusto.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
edPrecoDeCusto.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
```

Observação: Não vou entrar no mérito do cálculo, apenas mostrar como se implementa o `OnFocusChangeListener`!